# SSH Not Responding

Tags: ssh

Today when I tried to ssh into a remote server with my own credentials, I got no response at all, the command just hanged there after I pressed enter.  I can ping the server and I also tried `nc -v -w 1 [host_ip_address] -z 22`, got `connection succeeded!`.  I can also telnet into port 22 on that server.  So I'm pretty sure the `ssh` daemon is running and it's listening to port 22.

`ssh -v username@[hostname]` gives me:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cp-scl001 [10.5.60.224] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/yongfezh/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
```

Then the command hanged on the last line.

I met such issue before, it was because some docker container running on it was producing too many logs, and used up all the disk spaces.  But I'm not sure why it prevented me from sshing in.  I'm not sure if it's the same cause this time.

For now, I think I just need a way to log into it first and then see what's going on in the server.

Comment: @J.Freebird:  You went to extra effort to hide username and hostname, and then quoted a large output that gives them both away. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this could easily be from a disk full problem.  You need a way other than the network to log into this server.  When I do network designs for clients I always advise having a plan for how to do remote access without relying on the server's network.  If you don't have any other option, I guess you need to trek down to the data center and get a console connected to it.

Comment: I can telnet to the server, can I restart the server in my telnet session?

Comment: @JFreebird: should be able to...but the easiest way to answer the new question would have just been to try it.  However, after you do this, you may want to disable it since telnet is notably insecure (e.g. it usually sends the password _in the clear_).  In any case you certainly should change any password that you enter through the telnet connection.